# create table with constraints from another table in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

**I want create table from another table with constraint?**

I used this query  "create table destination as select * from source;" fro table creation.

But its copy only the column name in table without column constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special table named `sqlite_master`, holding the full `CREATE TABLE` statement for each table (it's modified as appropriate during `ALTER TABLE`).

I would make my *application* retrieve that `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='source';
```

Then I would replace the table name right after `CREATE TABLE` tokens, and execute the result as a new sqlite query.

I don't think that it's possible to do in sqlite's *pure* SQL without extensions.